# Invoke-Command inside PROCESS not returning anything

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I'm trying to use Invoke-Command inside an advanced function to return an object with the workspaces.

This works:

```
$g = Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1,server2,server3 -ScriptBlock {
    $AgentCfg = New-Object -ComObject AgentConfigManager.MgmtSvcCfg
    $AgentCfg.GetCloudWorkspaces()
}
$g| Measure-Object
```

This does not, Measure-Object says there are 0 objects.

```
function Get-WorkspaceInfo {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
    [string[]]$ComputerName,
    [string]$ErrorLog
    )

    BEGIN {}

    PROCESS {
        foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
            write-verbose "$Computer Iteration"


            $RemoteWorkspaces = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
                $AgentCfg = New-Object -ComObject AgentConfigManager.MgmtSvcCfg
                $OMSWorkspaces = $AgentCfg.GetCloudWorkspaces()   }
            $RemoteWorkspaces | Measure-Object
           

        }
    }

    END {}
}

Get-Workspaceinfo -ErrorLog x.txt -ComputerName server1,server2,server3 -Verbose
```

Comment: Remove `$OMSWorkspaces = ` (or add `$OMSWorkspaces` or `Write-Output $OMSWorkspaces` on the next line)

Comment: I tried all those suggestions, it still returns nothing/count O, EDIT: Ok, that's very weird, it works fine after I close the ISE and re-open it. Weird..